# Hiding Columns in PysimpleGUI and displaying another column, not erasing previous space

Tags: python

I have a 2 dimensional list l, whose first element in each list has a name. I want to pop out elements that have different names from given name

```
def Namesearch(l, rowid, name):
    n = len(l)
    for i in range(0,n):
        if l[i][0]!=name:
            l.pop(i)
            rowid.pop(i)
    ret = [l,rowid]
    print(ret)
```

I am able to print out l[i][0], but for some reason when I try to pop l[i] It shows an error that the list index is out of range. What's the issue here?

Comment: Modifying an iterable while looping over it is generally a bad idea! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating . One way to overcome this problem can be looping in reverse order: `for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):`

Comment: Yeah, thanks had already solved it by the time I saw your comment, honestly should have thought of it before. 
I used a different method, I initalised a variable count to 0, and everywhere i was mentioned, I changed it to i-count and incremented count every time the list was popped